# Any easy way to chain two comparison <=> operators in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, comparison, comparison-operators

Ruby comes with the handy `<=>` comparison operators, and native primitive types support them. I am wondering if there is an easy way to combine them to compare more complex objects, like Structs.For example, given

```
class Datum < Struct.new(:code, :volume); end

datum1 = Datum.new('B',10)
datum2 = Datum.new('A',10)
datum3 = Datum.new('C',11)

data = [datum1, datum2, datum3]
```

I would like to sort `data` by `volume` and then, if `volume`s are equal, by `code`. Like

```
data.sort {|a,b| (a.volume <=> b.volume) ??? (a.code <=> b.code)}
```

What should I put in `???`?

I am after a solution that:

- avoids recalculation of `<=>`
- One liner
- short ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a simple case as outlined above, you can use `sort_by`:

```
data.sort_by {|a| [a.volume, a.code] }
#=> [
#     #<struct Datum code="A", volume=10>,
#     #<struct Datum code="B", volume=10>,
#     #<struct Datum code="C", volume=11>
#   ]
```

If you're only sorting by a single attribute, it gets even shorter:

```
data.sort_by(&:volume)
#=> [
#     #<struct Datum code="B", volume=10>,
#     #<struct Datum code="A", volume=10>,
#     #<struct Datum code="C", volume=11>
#   ]
```

where `&:volume` uses `Symbol#to_proc` and is shorthand for `proc {|a| a.volume }` (similar to lambda).

If you need to make it more complex (i.e. have different left and right sides), you can expand this to a call to `sort`:

```
data.sort {|a,b| [a.volume, a.code] <=> [b.volume, b.code] }
#=> [
#     #<struct Datum code="A", volume=10>,
#     #<struct Datum code="B", volume=10>,
#     #<struct Datum code="C", volume=11>
#   ]
```

This whole thing works, because the `<=>` operator defined on `Array` does exactly what you need, for arbitrary levels.

Comment: I asked for a one-liner and `data.sort {|a,b| [a.volume, a.code] <=> [b.volume, b.code] }` certainly is, thanks @p11y!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Why don't you save yourself the trouble and add an `<=>` operator to `Datum`? Something like this:

```
class Datum < Struct.new(:code, :volume)
  def <=>(other)
    if(self.code < other.code)
      -1
    elsif(self.code > other.code)
      1
    elsif(self.volume < other.volume)
      -1
    elsif(self.volume > other.volume)
      1
    else
      0
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can say `data.sort` and be done with it. And once you have an `<=>` operator, you could [`include Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html) and get `<`, `<=`, ... operators for free.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby way to chain comparators is to use [`Numeric.nonzero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F):

```
data.sort {|a,b| (a.volume <=> b.volume).nonzero? || a.code <=> b.code}
```

What does `Numeric.nonzero?` do? It returns the number in case it is different from zero, otherwise it returns `nil`. The `||` operator then takes care of the rest, because `nil` is treated as `false` in a boolean context, thus `nil || b` is the same as `b`.

This being said, in most situations you will get shorter code when using [`Enumerable.sort_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) and return an array to indicate sort order:

```
data.sort_by {|a| [a.volume, a.code] }
```

It is also easier to reverse a sort order than when using the comparator:

```
data.sort {|a,b| (-(a.volume <=> b.volume)).nonzero? || a.code <=> b.code}
# vs.
data.sort_by {|a| [-a.volume, a.code] }
```

Warning: Be aware that [`sort_by` is slower than `sort` in case the comparator is fast](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) and conversely that `sort_by` is better in case the comparator is slow.